# can I use @reboot in cron.d files?

Tags: cron

I want to run a job with cron on reboot as a particular user.  I have been able to do this successfully using crontab to write to /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username with something like:

```
 @reboot ./run.sh >>~/tracefile 2>&1
```

However, I want to use /etc/cron.d/filename.  Cron jobs in this file require an extra column to indicate what user runs, so I use:

```
 @reboot wwwuser ./run.sh >>~/tracefile 2>&1
```

This doesn't seem to work.  Should I be able to use @reboot with a username in a cron.d file?

Comment: What flavor/version of cron? What OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, checking cron...

Comment: I don't know how to check cron version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that instead of adding `@reboot wwwuser ...` to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/username`, you should run `crontab -e` as user **wwwuser** and add:

```
@reboot ./run.sh >>~/tracefile 2>&1
```

Just in case make sure to use the full path to the script.

In case you're making these changes programmatically, you could try the following:

```
#write out current crontab
crontab -u wwwuser -l > mycron_wwwuser

#echo new cron into a temp cron file
echo "@reboot ./run.sh >>~/tracefile 2>&1" >> mycron_wwwuser

#install new cron file
crontab -u wwwuser mycron_wwwuser

#remove the temp cron file
rm mycron_wwwuser
```

... or better this one:

```
crontab -u wwwuser -l | { cat; echo "@reboot ./run.sh >>~/tracefile 2>&1"; } | crontab -u wwwuser -
```

Comment: I'm making these changes programmatically, so I don't think I can use the interactive editor (crontab -e).

Comment: @fschwiet, I've updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: This did help.  I did some things wrong when I originally tried to use crontab -u and now I see how to do that correctly.

Comment: I still wonder if I can etc/cron.d, I read someplace that /var/spool/cron data (where crontab writes to) can be lost (in particular, when upgrading cron).